# auto_increment_increment resets after mysql restart?

Tags: server, mysql

I am setting the MySQL variable `auto_increment_increment` using the following command.

`mysql -u root -p -e "SET GLOBAL auto_increment_increment = 10;"`

And it all works, until I restart MySQL (using `sudo service mysql restart`), then the variables are back to default.

Before restarting:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_%';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| auto_increment_increment | 10    |
| auto_increment_offset    | 1     |
+--------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

After restarting:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_%';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| auto_increment_increment | 1     |
| auto_increment_offset    | 1     |
+--------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can I make this changes permanent?

Comment: As far as I know you can't.  The mysql documentation states that what you set persists until the server is restarted, then the value is regenerated based on the contents of the table.  This mechanism isn't perfect (in fact I'd say it's hugely broken).  See for example: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=21641 (not quite the same issue, but I think basically the same root cause)

Comment: Hmm... Thanks for pointing that out @ssta. However, would it not be possible using a startup shell script or something like that then? It still really sucks that this is not supported, I am thinking of switching to MariaDB instead of MySQL.

Comment: No worries.  Not sure that MariaDB does any better in this respect.  You could certainly run a script on startup, yes.  I'm not sure, but perhaps it might be possible to set the value in the server configuration file?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-system-variables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command changes the behavior only temporary.
Therefore add a new configuration in `/etc/mysql/conf.d/`. Avoid changes in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. Why? See at the end of my answer.

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
```

and add

```
[mysqld]
auto-increment-increment = 10
```

Reload the configuration or restart the server.

---

Taken from the standard `my.cnf`

```
#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by ssta, you can use a configuration file.  Probably the best place for it would be the `my.cnf` file, used at startup.
Make the following changes:

```
...
[mysqld]
auto_increment_increment = 10
...
```

Save the file and restart the server.

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

That should work (I did not test it myself).  By curisoity, why do you want such a behaviour?